# std::getline from istream into string[] multiple times blank

Tags: c++, file, buffer, getline, istream

So I've got this constructor

```
A::A(std::istream& is)
{
if (validation(is))
{
    std::string line[SIZE];
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while((std::getline (is, line[i])&& i < SIZE))
    {
        i++;
    }
....
```

validation looks like this, it stores the IS in line and make some test and return a bool.
It works just fine, but the second getline in this constructor is blank(nothing stored in line). 
If I comment out validation, it works just fine.
So I guess it's something with getline and buffer. I tried to clear but i'm not good with stream.

If anyone have a guess, thx!

Main

```
ifstream myfile("file.txt");
A a(myfile);
```

validation.cpp

```
bool validation(std::istream& is)
{
string line[SIZE];
unsigned int i = 0;

bool valide = false;

while((std::getline(is, line[i])&& i < SIZE))
{
    i++;
}
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `validation` has a `while((std::getline(p_is, line[i]) && i < SIZE))` loop, those lines it gets are gone from the stream and won't be seen by the `getline` directly in `A::A`.  For that reason, `getline()` returns `false` and your `while` loop exits, and any `line[]` elements at or beyond `i` will still be empty.

It's relatively unusual to want a separate validation function... just try to read in to the variables that will store the data, validating as you go.

If you're determined to do validation separately, you can seek to the start of the file after validating with `is.seekg(0)` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) for docs), or even reopen the file..